# How to prevent the mode line color from changing after the buffer is switched?

Tags: faces, mode-line

like this:
[image]

The mode line color of the current buffer is darker, I hope the color will not change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The appearance of the mode-line is governed by two faces: `mode-line` and `mode-line-inactive`. The former has a `style` of `raised`, and the foreground/background colours are different. Just

<kbd>M-x customize-face RET mode-line,mode-line-inactive RET</kbd>

and adjust as desired.

Note that in emacs-29 there will be a `mode-line-active` face as well which inherits from `mode-line`.